# the limit of a limit

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following true in general?
(#):'If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists, then there exists some neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that for every $y \in U$, $\lim_{x \to y} f(x)$ exists.'
Furthermore, if $f$ is a function such that (#) holds, is the following true?
$\lim_{y \to a}\left(\lim_{x \to y} f(x)\right)$ exists and is equal to $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$.'

Answer (score 1):

The first is not true for example consider 
$$f(x)= x \cdot D(x)$$ 
where $D$ is the Dirichlet Function (the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$.

The second one is true as the composition of the continuous function $x\mapsto x$ with $f(x)$ will be continuous.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on the second question? I do not quite see how it is the composition of two functions.
If g is defined as $g(x) = \lim_{u \to x} f(u)$, then the concerned limit is $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$. I do not quite see how g can be written as a composition.